# Accessing InputFields within dynamic graphics without multiple clicks

Tags: graphics, dynamic, inputfield

I'm trying to write a timetable application.  (The activity blocks are to be resizable and reorderable.)  A problem I have run into, which might be a showstopper for this approach, is that entering times (minutes) and activities into the InputFields requires multiple clicks into the graphic.  Is there a way make the InputFields as accessible as the buttons?  (Only the "+" buttons work at the moment.)

```
Clear[timetable, entry, del, add, activity, mins]

newentry[num_, ypos_] := Inset[Graphics[{ColorData[24][num],
    Rectangle[{0, 0}, {400, -100}],
    Inset[Button["-", del[num]], {40, -12}],
    Inset[InputField[Dynamic[mins[num]], Number,
      FieldSize -> 4], {40, -40}],
    Inset[InputField[Dynamic[activity[num]], String,
      BaseStyle -> {FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 22},
      FieldSize -> 8], {200, -40}],
    Inset[Button["+", add[num]], {40, -85}],
    Inset[Button["Up"], {360, -12}],
    Inset[Button["Dn"], {360, -85}]
    }, PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, -100}}, ImageSize -> 400],
  {0, ypos}, {0, 0}, {400, 100}]

add[prev_] := Module[{},
  num = prev + 1;
  ypos = entry[prev][[-3, 2]] - 100;
  entry[num] = newentry[num, ypos]]

num = 1;
entry[num] = Inset[Graphics[{ColorData[24][num],
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {400, -100}],
     Inset[Button["-", del[1]], {40, -12}],
     Inset[InputField[Dynamic[mins[1]], Number,
       FieldSize -> 4], {40, -40}],
     Inset[InputField[Dynamic[activity[1]], String,
       BaseStyle -> {FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 22},
       FieldSize -> 8], {200, -40}],
     Inset[Button["+", add[1]], {40, -85}],
     Inset[Button["Up"], {360, -12}],
     Inset[Button["Dn"], {360, -85}]
     }, PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, -100}}, ImageSize -> 400],
   {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {400, 100}];
timetable = Dynamic[Graphics[{Yellow,
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {400, -500}],
     Array[entry, num]
     }, PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, -500}}, ImageSize -> 400],
   TrackedSymbols :> {num}];

timetable
```

[image]

Comment: Tabbing into fields is quite handy.

Comment: Check out https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TimerTable

Answer (score 1):

Deploy seems to do the trick.

```
timetable = Deploy[Dynamic[Graphics[{Yellow,
      Rectangle[{0, 0}, {400, -500}],
      Array[entry, num]
      }, PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, -500}}, ImageSize -> 400],
    TrackedSymbols :> {num}]];
```